# Phonegap: Image Capture orientation going wrong after upload

Tags: ios, cordova

I am developing a Phonegap application for IOS and I want to use Capture plugin for it. I have installed the plugin using CLI and added permissions in the config.xml file but the plugin os not working it do not show any output or error.

Basically the problem I have is with the image orientation when image captured from the camera. The image rotates in landscape direction.

1. I have tried to read the exif data in PHP but IOS trims the exif data from image before sending it to the server
2. I have installed the capture plugin but it is not working on IOS 7.1

I just need to make the orientation of the image right when taken from the camera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the .getPicture() call you can set the option

```
correctOrientation: true
```

This solved my problem of portrait images turning horizontal however on my LG G2 significant lag was added during the capture process when this flag was set. I'm still trying to figure out a server-side fix but with some EXIF data being stripped it's a bit challenging.

Docs explain a little more:
http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.camera

> correctOrientation: Rotate the image to correct for the orientation of the device during capture. (Boolean)